# Adding cards to Android Pay on rooted device

Tags: root-access, google-pay

As the new Android Pay app is now rolling out, I wanted to go ahead and get it set up on my device. Now, as many are finding out, rooted devices will receive the message "Android Pay cannot be used - Google is unable to verify that your device or software running on it is Android compatible".

Now, one fix that I have found is to temporarily disable Root in SuperSU where the message "Superuser is disabled and hidden" appears. After doing this, adding cards is supposed to give no errors.

Unfortunately, I can still not seem to add any cards. Is there any other way I can get google to recognize my device?

> Sony Xperia Z3 (D6616)
>
> Build #: 23.1.C.0.385
>
> SuperSU Version 2.49

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SuperSU, this *may* work: Disable it from the options menu

[image: Super SU Settings menu with "Enable Superuser" circled]

If this doesn't work, the other option is to fully uninstall SuperSU (or whatever you used to root your phone), add credit cards, and then boot into recovery again to reinstall SuperSU. You must do this every time you want to add any credit cards.