# Can't use android pay after removing root

Tags: root-access, google-pay

I had kingroot and I uninstalled it through kingroot uninstall option in the options menu. However, I still can't add a credit card to android pay. It says Google is unable to verify that your device or the software running on it is android compatible. I also tried deleting random folders I found with the name kingroot, I tried using ccleaner, and I tried deleting data from android pay and uninstall/reinstall android pay.

Comment: Did you actually *unroot* or just uninstall?

Comment: It said clear root and uninstall so I believe both.

Comment: [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3ldzx1/if_youve_unrooted_and_are_struggling_to_use/) recommends uninstalling Xposed framework as well. That helps?

Comment: I never installed it :/

Comment: Kingroot is notorious for being an a**hole. Its possible it left some residue matter unroot.

Comment: So do I really have to re-flash? Is there no way to get rid of it completely without doing so?

Comment: Related (but SuperSU instead of Kingroot): https://android.stackexchange.com/q/123529/251461

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I had to re-flash firmware for it to work. Instructions for re-flashing firmware for my specific device (lg g3) were incorrect which bricked my device. Luckily I found that clicking the other action mode than the one stated did the trick and my device was un-bricked. Was a scary few hours. At the end though my lg g3 worked and all residue of kingroot was gone!